# why only Abstract class can have constructor but Interface cannot, while I can create obj of both via Annonymous approach

Tags: java, interface, abstract-class

I studied on various platform that Interface cannot have constructor while abstract class can have. One reason for which we cannot have constructor in our interface is that all non static vars of class can be intitialized into constructor  and in Interface we can have only static one that too need to be initialized at time of declrn only.
Any other reason which can justify need to be shared. Because via Annonymous class object creation I can create Object of Interface and Abstract class both. And whatever Abstract methods I have inside my Interface I can define while creating the body of Annonymous.

Answer (score 1):

When you create an object from interface `new MyInterface() {...}`, the compiler actually creates an anonymous class that implements the interface.

Interfaces don't allow non-static members, so there is no point in having a constructor when there is nothing to initialize. Abstract classes can have non-static members to be initialized by constructor,

Read more about [anonymous classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html)

Comment: Hi cdalxndr , actually this is the point, we cannot instantiate Interface, but we can do via Anonymous concept. Similar to abstract class, then why abstract have constructor and Interface cannot

Comment: @Neeraj As interfaces aren't allowed to have non-static members, then what is the point of an interface constructor if there is nothing to initialize in it? Abstract classes can have non-static members to be initialized.

Comment: yes this point I agree and even mentioned in my query also. But I want to know is this the only reason for which we cannot have constructor or there are some other pointers to justify.

Comment: @Neeraj If it exists at least one reason for interfaces to not have constructors, then it is sufficient. Any more reasons are irrelevant.